# How to change default Nova Dropdown Dash (—)

Tags: laravel-nova

I have an BelongsTo Fields like this:

```
BelongsTo::make( __( 'Parent Page' ), 'parent', 'App\Nova\Page' )->nullable(),
```

In the Dropdown is as a Default Value a Dash (—) and I would like to change this label to something like "Main-Page".

What I have now:
[image: Situation Now]

What I want to have
[image: What I Want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using a `BelongsTo` field. The dash is hardcoded in the Vue component:

*vendor/laravel/nova/resources/js/components/Form/BelongsToField.vue*

```
<option value="" selected :disabled="!field.nullable">&mdash;</option>
```

This is used to create the first option in the select element.

Interestingly enough, it **is** possible using a `Select` field, which allows you to use the `withMeta()` function to set a placeholder. If you combine this with the `selected` meta value, you could create something like this:

```
Select::make('Parent Page')->options([
    'Page 1',
    'Page 2'
    // ... etc
])->withMeta([
    'placeholder' => 'Main-Page',
    'value' => null // or any value you'd like to use to pre-select an option
])->nullable()
```

Note: this is done using Nova 2. I Haven't tried it with v1.